# Showing multiple images in a horizontal scroll in an android app

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am a bit of an android app development noob, and am writing an app in which you take one or more pictures, and I would like to show these pictures sort of like the google play store shows images, where you scroll horizontally through the images. How would I do this?
Thanks.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHLpI.jpg)

Comment: you need to add sliding animation on imageview in android

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RecyclerView`

[follow the tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

`LayoutManager` is an object responsible for orientation (`HORIZONTAL` in your case)

instead of `LinearLayoutManager(Context context)`

use

`LinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout`